# When I install unity game engine on Ubuntu, it doesnt download c# like in windows

Tags: programming, c#, unity3d

I installed Unity( tutorial How can I install Unity 3D game engine for Ubuntu ?). It worked, but when I try to edit c# script, it does not work.
When I double-click the script in my Project view, nothing happens.

Comment: You could install Visual Studio Code manually if Unity didn't install it for you.

Comment: I installed it but it does not work

Comment: Can you run this C# console app from the terminal: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1100537/how-can-i-compile-run-and-decompile-c-code-in-ubuntu-terminal/1100539#1100539 ?