# How can I compile, run and decompile C# code in Ubuntu terminal?

Tags: command-line, compiling, mono, c#

I have a C# code which I need to compile, execute and decompile using the terminal.

How can I do so?

Comment: I think it would be easier to install VS code on Linux and then code in C#, as explained here, step by step: 
https://qawithexperts.com/article/c-sharp/hello-world-visual-studio-code-c-example/307

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `mono` which is `C#` implementation, having cross-platform support and is open source.

Open terminal and install mono:

#### For Ubuntu 20.04 [(Stable)](https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/)

```
sudo apt install gnupg ca-certificates
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
echo "deb https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-focal main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official-stable.list
sudo apt update
```

#### For Ubuntu 18.04

```
sudo apt install apt-transport-https dirmngr
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
echo "deb https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu vs-bionic main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official-vs.list
sudo apt update
```

#### For Ubuntu 16.04

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
sudo apt install apt-transport-https
echo "deb https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu vs-xenial main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official-vs.list
sudo apt update
```

#### For Ubuntu 14.04

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
sudo apt install apt-transport-https
echo "deb https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu vs-trusty main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official-vs.list
sudo apt update
```

Then type

```
sudo apt install mono-complete
```

Create a sample `C#` file in the current directory

For example you can use the following code:

```c#
class GoodDay
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Good Day!");
    }
}
```

Use any text editor like gedit, type the following code and save the file as `GoodDay.cs`

The command to compile the code -

```
mcs -out:GoodDay.exe GoodDay.cs
```

An executable file `GoodDay.exe`  is generated.

The command to execute the `.exe` file -

```
mono GoodDay.exe
```

The output will be -

```
Good Day!
```

The command to decompile the executable file -

```
monodis --output=GoodDay.txt GoodDay.exe
```

The decompiled code information is saved in the newly generated file `GoodDay.txt`

Answer (score 19):

You need to install *mono-complete* if you want to run software for Mono or Microsoft .NET which you are not installing from a Debian package.

---

1. Install *mono-complete*. In all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

   ```
   sudo apt install mono-complete
   ```
2. Save your C# code in a file called hello.cs. Example hello.cs code is:

   ```c#
   using System;

   namespace Project_1 {
       class MainClass {
           public static void Main (string[] args) {
               Console.WriteLine ("Hello World!");
               Console.ReadKey ();
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Make hello.cs executable. Right-click the hello.cs file -> select *Properties* -> *Permissions* tab -> put a check mark to the left of *Allow executing file as program*.
4. Change directories using the `cd` command to the directory that contains the hello.cs file.
5. Use the mcs compiler and create a Windows executable named *hello.exe* from the source hello.cs.

   ```
   mcs -out:hello.exe hello.cs
   ```
6. Run the hello.exe program with mono.

   ```
   mono hello.exe
   ```
7. The results of running your program in step 6. should be:

   ```
   Hello World!
   ```
8. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to exit back to a default terminal prompt.
9. Decompile the executable file.

   ```
   monodis --output=decompiled-hello.txt hello.exe
   ```

Comment: I don't think you have to perform Step 8

Comment: But I tested too and I did not need the Step 8, Oh ok I am sorry I did not put Console.ReadKey();

Comment: My bad for not including the sample hello.cs code that I used in Step 2 which I have edited my answer and included

Comment: why use Mono in 2018 when the official .NET Core has been available for Linux since 2016?

Answer (score 2):

The official [.NET Core](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Core) from Microsoft has been around since 2016. It's [open source software](https://github.com/dotnet/core) and supports many platforms. Even Mono now shares some code with .NET Core so there's almost no reason to use Mono in 2018

Just go to the [official website](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download) to download and install. If you want to install from command line then visit [Install .NET on Linux](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux), specifically [Install the .NET SDK or the .NET Runtime on Ubuntu](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu). To install the SDK and runtime with apt use

```
sudo apt-get update; \
  sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https && \
  sudo apt-get update && \
  sudo apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-5.0
```

You can also [install with snap](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-snap)

```
sudo snap install dotnet-sdk --classic --channel=5.0
```

Answer (score 0):

True open source solution as of 2021, is still Mono, available at their site https://www.mono-project.com/ Microsoft's implementation unsurprisingly doesnt work well (slow, unresponsive) on Linux. This is to be expected as Microsoft is a long time nemesis of Linux and its free, open source nature. Stick with Mono it is still developed and easily installable. Download Instructions on included link

Comment: Because I posted the top upvoted answer on this page, I've tried various iterations of .NET Core as an alternative to Mono, but I still haven't gotten it to work well in Ubuntu.