# Ubuntu Rider Process finished with exit code 139

Tags: 20.04

I wanted to execute a simple Hello World command in c# in my jetbrains rider environment, to test if it works, and I got this error: `Process finished with exit code 139`. What can I do to solve this for my case? I have not seen similar cases, only for python and other issues.

[image: rider hello world finished with exit code 139]

Comment: When a container exits with status code 139, it's because it received a SIGSEGV signal. The operating system terminated the container's process to guard against a memory integrity violation.  
 
There is problem in your code it has nothing to do with ubuntu please post in appropriate forum

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I compile, run and decompile C# code in Ubuntu terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1100537/how-can-i-compile-run-and-decompile-c-code-in-ubuntu-terminal)